# Oracle Regex grabbing value from key value pair in a string

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-replace

Consider the following column row:

```
col
-------------------------
'{"day":"8","every":"2"}'
```

I am trying to get 8 from this string using regular expression to figure out the day.

so far I have:

```
SELECT 
    regexp_replace(col, '{"day":[^0-9]', '') as "day"
FROM 
   mytable;
```

This gives me:

```
 day
 ---------------
 8","every":"2"}
```

I am having trouble figuring out how to filter out the rest of the string from the first number forward. In my example I just want the number 8 for this row.

Comment: I am using 11g.

Comment: Regex `^{"day":"(\d+).*}$` replace with `\1`

Comment: Perfect. That works. Can you explain what does the \1 do?

Comment: The `()` characters capture the digits and the `\1` says "give me the first capture group" (in this case the only one).

Comment: Awesome. Thanks you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
SELECT 
    regexp_replace(col, '{"day":"([0-9]+).*', '\1') as "day"
FROM 
   mytable;
```

Comment: that returns only "

Comment: @eddiem [^0-9] think this exclude digits

Comment: Sorry, my first answer was totally wrong, but I think this one should work.

Answer (score 3):

When you are lucky enough to use Oracle 12c Release 1 (12.1.0.2) or later, do take a look at [**JSON_VALUE**](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions093.htm#SQLRF56668)

```
WITH t (s)
AS (
    SELECT '{"day":"8","every":"2"}'
    FROM DUAL
    )
SELECT JSON_VALUE(s, '$.day'  ) AS day
    ,  JSON_VALUE(s, '$.every') AS every
FROM t;

DAY   EVERY
---   -----
8     2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to `JSON_VALUE()` then I would recommend the following regex unless you always know the position of the `day` key in the JSON string:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '^.*"day":"(\d+)".*$', '\1') AS day
  FROM mytable;
```

This will replace the entire string (assuming it matches!) with the contents of the first capturing group (enclosed in parentheses: `(\d+)`). `\d` indicates a digit `0-9`. If you want to return NULL values as well, you can replace `\d+` with `\d*`. If negative or non-numeric values are possible, then I would recommend the following:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '^.*"day":"([^"]*)".*$', '\1') AS day
  FROM mytable;
```

This will return whatever characters that might be contained in the `day` key.

FYI, once you have the value, numeric or non-, you can convert it to a number safely by using `TO_NUMBER()` along with `REGEXP_SUBSTR()`:

```
SELECT COALESCE( TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( REGEXP_REPLACE( col, '^.*"day":"[^"]*".*$', '\1' ), '\d+' ) ), 0 ) AS day
  FROM mytable;
```

Hope it helps.